# Bin size not correct for paid time off hours per employee?

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have a workbook with employee time off hours. The hours are in a field called [Approved]. I wanted to get a count of days (approved hours / 8 = 1 day of PTO) employees were taking and Bin them.

```
{ FIXED [Employee ID1]:SUM([Approved])/8}
```

and then I created Bin sizes of 10. It seems like the correct way to go about it, but for some reason it's showing 2022 had employees with 80+ days off.

[image]

but when you look at the data to show employee days (approved hours / 8), it shows the most an employee had was 71 days in 2022:

[image]

any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: You may need to add the year or date to your fixed calculation. Unless this is fake data, how have people already taken 80+ days off in 2024? Also are you bins calculated using every 10 in `[Accepted]` or every 10 in `[Accepted]/8`?